# How do I extract both filled and empty xml tags using regular expressions in Java?

Tags: java, regex, xml, soap

I am currently working with a SOAP service that returns XML code in the following style:

```
...
<PremiseId>12345</PremiseId>
<StreetNumber>12</StreetNumber>
<StreetName>Example Street</StreetName>
...
```

A call to the SOAP service returns a large dataset with potentially hundreds of premises. I want to grab the street names out of this, and currently I am using the following:

```
ArrayList<String> streetNames = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<StreetName>([\s\w]+)</StreetName>", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(matchString);

while(m.find())
{
    streetNames.add(m.group(1));
}
```

This works for the most part, however, some of the street names in the database are NULL and will return a value like:

```
<StreetName/>
```

Which is ignored. This is a problem as it leaves gaps in the ArrayList where there should be premises. I need these blank StreetName tags to insert a blank string ("") into the ArrayList instead.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Regular expressions are fundamentally the wrong tool for parsing XML.  Use a real XML parser or XPath instead and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: You can consider using XPath to find the `<StreetName>` elements.

Comment: I found a nice tutorial on parsing the string through DOM to extract the elements. Worked much nicer than regex and much simpler. Thanks for the tips.